# Move in a 45 degree direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to trying to get all three of my images to fly off the screen in different 45 degree directions. Right now I have all of them flying off the screen to the left, but as I said I would like them to fly of in 45 degree directions. I have included the css, html, and the javascript that I have thus far. I am believing that the solution is a simple fix in the javascript but, I am not that well versed writing javascript to figure it out. If someone could please help me it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

HTML:

```
<button onclick="slideIn('img6','img5','img2');">slide in</button>
<button onclick="slideOut('img5','img6','img2');">slide out</button>
```

CSS:

```
#img2{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:300px;
    height:119px;
    margin-top:250px;
    margin-left:-200px;
}
#img5{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    height:170px;
    width:333px;
    margin-top:130px;
    margin-left:72px;
}
#img6{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    height:184px;
    width:414px;
    margin-top:290px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
        function slideIn(skate,blanket,clothes){
            var elem = document.getElementById(skate);
            var elem1 = document.getElementById(blanket);
            var elem2 = document.getElementById(clothes);
                elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0s";
                elem.style.position="absolute";
                elem.style.top = "50%";
                elem.style.left = "50%";
                elem.style.marginLeft = "100px";
                elem.style.marginTop = "290px";


                elem1.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0s";
                elem1.style.position="absolute";
                elem1.style.top = "50%";
                elem1.style.left = "50%";
                elem1.style.marginLeft = "72px";
                elem1.style.marginTop = "130px";

                elem2.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0s";
                elem2.style.position="absolute";
                elem2.style.top = "50%";
                elem2.style.left = "50%";
                elem2.style.marginLeft = "-200px";
                elem2.style.marginTop = "250px";

}


        function slideOut(skate,blanket,clothes){
            var elem = document.getElementById(skate);
            var elem1 = document.getElementById(blanket);
            var elem2 = document.getElementById(clothes);

                elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-out 0s";
                elem.style.left = "-600px";

                elem1.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-out 0s";
                elem1.style.left = "-1200px";

                elem2.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-out 0s";
                elem2.style.left = "-1200px";


}
        </script>
```

Comment: Check out css3 transforms and/or using a plugin (if you're not adverse to using jQuery. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: I agree. The answer I posted below works just as well with css3 transforms (specifically css transitions. I highly recommend checking out this link to learn: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: I would rather not, this is less bulky. I believe the answer has to do with the style.transition = " here is where I believe the answer is";

Comment: For the record... This is much MORE bulky. The same animations can be accomplished with just a few lines of code using css. =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the elements slideOut at an equal rate on the y and x axis.

Example: if they move left 600px then it needs to also move toward the top 600px (this will make it fly to the upper-left at a 45deg angle. Alternatively, if you moved it 600px left and 600px toward the bottom, it will fly to the lower left. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, so I tried it and it does something funky. Maybe, I am not writing it correctly. Is there some way to write this differently?                                                         Here is what I wrote:                                        elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-out 0s";
   elem.style.left = "-600px";
   elem.style.top = "600px";

Comment: Could you include a jsfiddle?

Comment: It would just help if I could see the whole thing. =)